# Remove specific list item from DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists

I have the following unordered list in my DOM. I am currently searching for a method, that can delete a specific list item using Javascript.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li id="1">Depy</li>
  <li id="2">HI</li>
  <li id="3">WA</li>
  <li id="4">FA</li>
</ul>
```

I am creating a function in JS, which accepts a string argument. For example "FA" and then it is supposed to delete find and delete list items containing string in their content.

To Sum up I want to delete by specific list element by if it has a matched string in content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of `li` elements, then iterate through them and delete the item with the correct content:

```js
function removeListItemByText(text) {
  const li = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
  li.forEach(elem => {
    if (elem.innerText == text) elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  });
}

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  removeListItemByText("FA");
};
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li id="1">Depy</li>
  <li id="2">HI</li>
  <li id="3">WA</li>
  <li id="4">FA</li>
</ul>

<button id="button">Remove FA</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack Bashford in my case it was innerText not innerHTML but appreciate it ;)

Comment: No worries @Learner33 - fixed answer too ;)

Comment: @JackBashford why is this part in square brackets with dots at the beginning? `[...document.querySelectorAll("li")];` Surely `document.querySelectorAll('li");` will work just as it is?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('li')` returns a NodeList - the `[...]` is spread notation and converts it into an array so I can use `forEach`.